# Where is a good description of User Login values in SharePoint 2010 with and without claims?

Tags: claims-based-auth

If I look at HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name I get values that map to what I see in the content database in UserInfo.tp_Login.

Since I have enabled both Windows Authentication and Forms Based Authentication (claims) in my SharePoint 2010 web application I see values like the following for UserInfo.tp_Login.

```
<netbios_domain>\<samAccountName>
i:0#.w|<netbios_domain>\<samAccountName>
i:0#.f|<provider_name>|<claimsUserId>
```

For example:

```
MYDOMAIN\john.doe
i:0#.w|mydomain\john.doe
i:0#.f|ldapmember|john.doe@mydomain.com
```

Is there a good guide as to what the valid formats are here?  I need to parse this information unless there is something handy function that I can use.  I checked SPUtility and SPUtility.GetAccountName didn't seem to help.

I'm pretty sure that the "w" in "i:0#.w" means Windows and the "f" in "i:0#.f" means Forms, but I'm wondering if there is an enumerated list of possibilities somewhere.

Comment: The good news is that AD users apparently cannot have a "\" or a "|" in the account name, so I may just be able to use those as a delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out http://blog.mastykarz.nl/programmatically-converting-login-name-claim/

Yes, there's a handy function

Comment: Perfect.  It doesn't quite explain all the pieces and parts, but it does provide code for parsing it.  It will be interesting to see if it works with non-claims accounts (I suspect not).

Comment: I see that there is a SPClaimProviderManager.IsClaimsUser() method which should help.

Answer (score 0):

There is an explanation in the whitepaper "Implementing Claims-Based Authentication with SharePoint Server 2010". You can download it [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=229109).

On page 62, "Claims Encoding", you read:

> w/m/r/t/p/s = Original Issuer Type -> w = windows, m = membership, r = role, t = trusted STS, p = personal card, s= local sts claim

The rest of the string is explained too.

Update: I just found a full description on [technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13921.sharepoint-2013-and-sharepoint-2010-claims-encoding.aspx).